# Variable undefined in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I want to make a sticky nav bar for my website in react and I have some javascript code and when i run it I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined` when I do `Console.log(nav)` it says that it is defined but when I do `console.log(sticky)` it says that it is not defined and that why I get the error because I am trying to run `remove` on something that it is not defined.

```
import React from "react"
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import './App.css';


export default function App (){
  const navStyle = {
     color: "white"
  };
    // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
  window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

  // Get the navbar
  var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
  console.log(nav)

  // Get the offset position of the navbar
  var sticky = nav.offsetTop;
  console.log(sticky)

  // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
  function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      nav.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
      nav.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="App-header">
      <nav className="nav">
        <h3>Logo</h3>
        <ul>
          <Link style={navStyle} to="/">
              <li>Home</li>
          </Link>
          <Link style={navStyle} to="LogIn">
            <li>Log In</li>
          </Link>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The error says that the problem is on the line `nav.classList.remove("sticky")`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is not the react way of doing things. You should use  `useRef` and `useEffect`

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that you `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements. You only need to get first element. But this is not the correct way of doing this thing with react hooks. You should use `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks

```
import React from "react"
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import './App.css';


export default function App (){
  const navStyle = {
     color: "white"
  };
  const navRef= useRef(null);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction);
    () => { window.removeEventListener('scroll', myFunction) }
  }, []) 
  // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
  function myFunction() {
    var nav = navRef.current
    console.log(nav)

    // Get the offset position of the navbar
    var sticky = nav.offsetTop;
    console.log(sticky)
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      nav.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
      nav.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="App-header">
      <nav ref={navRef} className="nav">
        <h3>Logo</h3>
        <ul>
          <Link style={navStyle} to="/">
              <li>Home</li>
          </Link>
          <Link style={navStyle} to="LogIn">
            <li>Log In</li>
          </Link>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to access the first element of the `nav` class.
You were trying to get the property from the array of elements, which is not correct.

This should work:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const navStyle = {
    color: "white"
  };
  // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
  window.onscroll = function () {
    myFunction();
  };

  // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
  function myFunction() {
    var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0];
    var sticky = nav.offsetTop;
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      nav.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      nav.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App-header">
      <nav className="nav">
        <h3>Logo</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Log In</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bush-w6304?file=/src/App.js:0-823